# In useEffect, what's the difference between providing no dependency array and an empty one?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I gather that the `useEffect` Hook is run after every render, if provided with an empty dependency array:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  performSideEffect();
}, []);
```

But what's the difference between that, and the following?

```js
useEffect(() => {
  performSideEffect();
});
```

Notice the lack of `[]` at the end. The linter plugin doesn't throw a warning.

Answer (score 401, accepted):

It's not quite the same.

- Giving it an empty array acts like `componentDidMount` as in, it only runs once.
- Giving it no second argument acts as both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`, as in it runs first on mount and then on every re-render.
- Giving it an array as second argument with any value inside, eg `, [variable1]` will only execute the code inside your `useEffect` hook ONCE on mount, as well as whenever that particular variable (variable1) changes.

You can read more about the second argument as well as more on how hooks actually work on the official docs at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Is there a use-case for ever putting `null`? Isn't it just the same as not putting the code in a useEffect hook?

Comment: @Patrick `useEffect` will be run __after render__ while just putting the code there will be run __before render__

Comment: according to a note in: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect,
passing empty array will cause run it also on `componentWillUnmount` in addition to `componentDidMount`

Comment: When I give the dependency array a variable (Ex: [myList]) to display my list items after I insert them with `axios.post` and I see that it keeps sending requests every second in my Network tab. Will this affect the performance of my app?

Comment: well, yes. you're basically running an infinite loop

Comment: @Patrick Putting dependency as null is same as having empty array. It will on render content inside useEffect once.

Comment: Is there an official name for the empty array pattern? So far I only see this circumscribed and it's hard to google for questions I have that are related to this pattern.

Answer (score 26):

Just an addition to `@bamtheboozle's` answer.

If you return a clean up function from your `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  performSideEffect();
  return cleanUpFunction;
}, []);
```

It will run before every `useEffect` code run, to clean up for the previous useEffect run. (Except the very first useEffect run)

Comment: You forgot to mention that the cleanup function will also always run on unmount. So, for example, if the dependency array is empty (`[]`), then the cleanup function will only run once: on unmount. See "Notes" section [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) (scroll down).

Answer (score 6):

Late to the party but thought of putting this example here which I did for my own understanding after reading above comments:

```
import './App.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  const [name, setName] = useState('John');
   useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("1- No dependency array at all");
  });
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("2- Empty dependency array");
  }, []);
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("3- Dependency array with state");
  }, [name]);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setName('Jane');
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click to update state</button>
      <p>{`Name: ${name}`}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

OUTPUT

***On page load***

```
 1- No dependency array at all
 2- Empty dependency array
 3- Dependency array with state
 1- No dependency array at all
 2- Empty dependency array
 3- Dependency array with state
```

***On button click -state update***

```
 1- No dependency array at all
 3- Dependency array with state
```

Comment: Everywhere I see says that an empty array will run only once. I'm trying to use this to bind an event handler. but with empty array it don't run at all.

Answer (score 3):

The latest docs have a good rundown on the differences:

https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#examples-dependencies

**Passing an array**

If you specify the dependencies, your Effect runs after the initial render and after re-renders with changed dependencies.

```
useEffect(() => {}, [a, b]);
```

**Passing an empty array**

If your Effect truly doesn’t use any reactive values, it will only run after the initial render (though twice in development). This now causes a linter warning.

```
useEffect(() => {}, []);
```

**Passing no array**

If you pass no dependency array at all, your Effect runs after every single render (and re-render) of your component.

```
useEffect(() => {});
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that if you don't provide the empty array dependency, the useEffect() hook will be executed on both mount and update.