# What is the point of useEffect() if you don't specify a dependancy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am using react hooks in a functional component, and was wondering what the use of `useEffect` is when you don't specify a dependency. I know the docs state it is used for side effects, but my question is why can't these side effects just be run with plain JS inside the functional component? As a very basic example I was playing with the following code:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

function Child () {

  const [clickCount, updateCount] = useState(0)

  console.log('Run outside of useEffect')

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("Run inside of useEffect")
  })


  return (

    <button onClick = {() => updateCount(clickCount+1)}> Child COmponent </button>
  )
}

export default Child
```

As you would expect given it is basically just a normal JS function, on every re-render caused by a button click, both `console.log`'s are executed.

I understand why you may want to use `useEffect` in a situation such as below, where you only want to run `useEffect` if something specific changes:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

function Child () {

  const [clickCount, updateCount] = useState(0)

  console.log('Run outside of useEffect')

  //this now only runs when `someVariable` changes
  useEffect(()=>{
    
    console.log("Run inside of useEffect")
  }, [someVariable])


  return (

    <button onClick = {() => updateCount(clickCount+1)}> Child COmponent </button>
  )
}

export default Child
```

But this begs the question, what is the point of using `useEffect` unless you specify the dependency matrix as a second argument? Can't side effects just be run normally using plain JS?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579426/in-useeffect-whats-the-difference-between-providing-no-dependency-array-and-an

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In useEffect, what's the difference between providing no dependency array and an empty one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579426/in-useeffect-whats-the-difference-between-providing-no-dependency-array-and-an)

Comment: @Naren i wouldn't say its a duplicate as i wasn't asking what the purpose of using the dependency array was, which is what that question addresses. I think the difference in the answers given for this question compared to that one reflect the difference between the two questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the point of using useEffect unless you specify the dependency
> matrix as a second argument?

Specifying the dependency array is an optimization to tell React to skip executing the effect if certain values haven't changed between different renders of a component.

> Can't side effects just be run normally using plain JS?

Effects that are executed at the top-level inside functional component execute in a different way as compared to the effect inside the `useEffect` hook.

When effects are inside the `useEffect`:

- They are executed after browser has painted the screen, i.e. after React has applied changes to the DOM.
- Before running the effect again, `useEffect` can run the clean-up function, if clean-up function is provided.
- Specifying the dependency array will allow you to skip running the effect after every re-render of the component.
- Omitting the array may cause an infinite re-render.

Because of the above mentioned points, you always want the side-effects to be executed inside the `useEffect` hook.

As far as the effects at the top-level code in the functional component are concerned, consider the following points:

- Will execute the effect before user sees anything on the screen, i.e. effect will execute before React updates the DOM.
- You will have no clean-up mechanism that could be executed before running the effect again.

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

> effects scheduled with `useEffect` don’t block the browser from updating the screen. This makes your app feel more responsive. The majority of effects don’t need to happen synchronously.

Code inside `useEffect` hook is run after the DOM update. That's the difference.

Example:

```js
function App() {

  let [hi, setHi] = React.useState(false);
  let [inEffect, setInEffect] = React.useState(true);
  let msg = inEffect ? "useEffect (DOM will be updated immediately)" : "functional component (it will block DOM update)";
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>
        Long-running code is in {msg} {" "}
        <button onClick={() => (setInEffect(!inEffect), setHi(false))}>switch</button>
      </p>
      <button onClick={() => setHi(true)}>Say Hi</button>
      { hi ? <Hi {...{inEffect}}/> : null }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Hi({inEffect}) {
  !inEffect && block();
  React.useEffect(() => inEffect && block());
  return <h1>Hi!</h1>
}

function block(time = 2000) {
  const now = Date.now();
  while(now + time > Date.now());
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```