# Why do I not get into a React infinite re-render loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, use-effect

I've always thought that having any form of `setState` inside a `useEffect` call would result in an infinite re-render loop due to the `useEffect` being called on each render. But for some reason my code is fine and my Next.js application runs perfectly. Could I know what the gaps in my knowledge are?

```js
const [base, setBase] = useState(DEFAULT_BASE)
const [rateData, setRateData] = useState([])
const [symbolList, setSymbolList] = useState([])

// At the start, we want to display the rates in terms of EUR
useEffect(async () => {
  const data = await calculator(FETCH_DATA, base)
  setRateData(data)
  // Create the symbol list
  const symbols = []
  Object.keys(data).map((c) =>
    symbols.push(c)
  )
  setSymbolList(symbols)
  console.log(symbolList)
}, [])
```

Comment: Your `useEffect` has empty dependencies, so why do you expect it to re-run? (disclaimer: I am not saying, that what you are doing is good or bad design-wise)

Comment: it will only run on every render if you omit the second parameter (no empty array).

Comment: Something unrelated but Don't use async for `useEffect` function. useEffect expects either nothing or a function to be returned which is usually known as a cleanup function. By writing `async` its returning a Promise. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In useEffect, what's the difference between providing no dependency array and an empty one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579426/in-useeffect-whats-the-difference-between-providing-no-dependency-array-and-an)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an empty array as an arg at the end.

UseEffect with an empty `[]` dependency array means that will only only run when the `componentDidMount`, this is only done when the component loads for the first time.

Not passing that argument will cause it to be called when any state variable is changed and one every re-render (similar to your expectation).

If you pass a variable to the array, then it will be called only when that variable changes. You can have more than one `useEffect` functions as well, so you can selectively render as well.

Read the Note here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html