# Having problems with Chart.js and Canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am currently using Graph.js to render graphs it is working on the initial render, but until I press setTimeformats buttons in order to show another graph on the same canvas, it is giving me  Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas can be reused. Am I using it properly? How Should I destroy the chart in order to use other graphs on the same canvas? Help would be very appreciated.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { historyOptions } from "../chartConfig/chartConfig";
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
interface Props{
  data:any
}

const ChartData:React.FC<Props> = ({ data}) => {
  const chartRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);
  const { day, week, year, detail } = data;
  const [timeFormat, setTimeFormat] = useState("24h");

  const determineTimeFormat = () => {
    switch (timeFormat) {
      case "24h":
        return day;
      case "7d":
        return week;
      case "1y":
        return year;
      default:
        return day;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (chartRef && chartRef.current && detail) {
  const chartInstance = new Chart(chartRef.current, {
        type: "line",

        data: {
          datasets: [
            {
              label: `${detail.name} price`,
              data: determineTimeFormat(),
              backgroundColor: "rgba(174, 305, 194, 0.5)",
              borderColor: "rgba(174, 305, 194, 0.4",
              pointRadius: 0,
            },
          ],
        },
        options: {
          ...historyOptions,
        },     
      });
       if (typeof chartInstance !== "undefined") chartInstance.destroy();
    }
  });
  const renderPrice = () => {
    if (detail) {
      return (
        <>
          <p className="my-0">${detail.current_price.toFixed(2)}</p>
          <p
            className={
              detail.price_change_24h < 0
                ? "text-danger my-0"
                : "text-success my-0"
            }
          >
            {detail.price_change_percentage_24h.toFixed(2)}%
          </p>
        </>
      );
    }
  };
  return (
    <div  className="bg-white border mt-2 rounded p-3">
      <div>{renderPrice()}</div> 
      <div>
        <canvas ref={chartRef} id="myChart" width={250} height={250}></canvas>
      </div>
      <div className="chart-button mt-1">
        <button
          onClick={() => setTimeFormat("24h")}
          className="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm"
        >
          24h
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => setTimeFormat("7d")}
          className="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm mx-1"
        >
          7d
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => setTimeFormat("1y")}
          className="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm"
        >
          1y
        </button> 
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChartData;
```

Comment: your useEffect is being triggered every time your state or props change: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579426/in-useeffect-whats-the-difference-between-providing-no-dependency-array-and-an). If that's intended, then you can either call `.destroy()` on the old chart instance if it exists, or from the looks of it, you just want to swap out the data in the first dataset, so you can likely call `.update()` after changing the data. [api spec here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html)

Comment: Actually sorry, I don't think you can easily retain the canvas instance (react will recreate it each render), so `.update()` won't work as expected. Better to destroy it.

Comment: @CallumMorrisson I have updated the code, could this work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you might solve this problem is by using a new state variable and `useEffect` to quickly remove and re-create the canvas element each time the timeFormat changes. Some key points here:

- As @CallumMorrisson mentioned, in order to understand this approach, it is extremely important to read and understand [this section](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) of the React docs about skipping the `useEffect` hook in its entirety.
- Using the `day`, `name`, `week`, `year` attributes directly in `useEffect` instead of the entire `data` variable makes sure that the chart instance is only re-created when necessary, not on every render. Same goes for the function `determineTimeFormat`, those types of functions should be defined outside the component's scope if possible.

```
const determineTimeFormat = (
  timeFormat: string,
  day: any,
  week: any,
  year: any
) => {
  switch (timeFormat) {
    case "24h":
      return day;
    case "7d":
      return week;
    case "1y":
      return year;
    default:
      return day;
  }
};

interface Props {
  data: any
}

const ChartData: React.FC<Props> = ({ data }) => {
  const chartCanvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);
  const { day, week, year, detail } = data;
  const { name } = detail;
  const [timeFormat, setTimeFormat] = useState("24h");
  const [isRebuildingCanvas, setIsRebuildingCanvas] = useState(false);

  // remove the canvas whenever timeFormat changes
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsRebuildingCanvas(true);
  }, [timeFormat]); // timeFormat must be present in deps array for this to work

  /* if isRebuildingCanvas was true for the latest render, 
    it means the canvas element was just removed from the dom. 
    set it back to false to immediately re-create a new canvas */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isRebuildingCanvas) {
      setIsRebuildingCanvas(false);
    }
  }, [isRebuildingCanvas]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const chartCanvas = chartCanvasRef.current
    if (isRebuildingCanvas || !chartCanvas) {
      return;
    }
    const chartInstance = new Chart(chartRef.current, {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        datasets: [
          {
            label: `${name} price`,
            data: determineTimeFormat(timeFormat, day, week, year),
            backgroundColor: "rgba(174, 305, 194, 0.5)",
            borderColor: "rgba(174, 305, 194, 0.4",
            pointRadius: 0,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        ...historyOptions,
      },
    });
    return () => {
      chartInstance.destroy();
    }
  }, [day, isRebuildingCanvas, name, timeFormat, week, year]);
  return (
    <>
      {isRebuildingCanvas ? undefined : (
        <canvas ref={chartCanvasRef} id='myChart' width={250} height={250} />
      )}
      <button onClick={() => setTimeFormat("24h")}>24h</button>
      <button onClick={() => setTimeFormat("7d")}>7d</button>
      <button onClick={() => setTimeFormat("1y")}>1y</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default ChartData;
```

Comment: Thank you, my guy