# How to pass data from async function to Drawer Navigator in React Native

Tags: react-native

im a new to react native but trying to build my own application.
I'm trying to pass storeKey and userName obtained from DB to CustomDrawer and Drawer.Screen so I don't need to repeat the function everytime.
so, it's working inside HomeScreen, console.log prints proper value. However, when I pass it in Drawer.Screen 'stock', and then print it in that module, it shows empty array.
How can I pass value from async to drawer navigator properly?
and how can I pass it to CustomDrawer? will {...props} already contain the value?
When I print props.params in the CustomDrawer module, it only says undefined..

```
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

const [storeKey, setStoreKey] = useState([]);
const [userName, setName] = useState([]);
useEffect(async() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    if(isMounted){
        console.log('zzzz')
        const auth = getAuth();
        const user = auth.currentUser;
        if(user !== null){
            const email = user.email;
            const UserInfo = await getDoc(doc(db, 'users', email));
            if(UserInfo.exists()){
                setName(UserInfo.data().name);
                setStoreKey(UserInfo.data().storeKey)
                return () => {
                    isMounted = false
                }
            }
            else{
                console.log('None')
            }
    }
}
}, [storeKey]);

console.log('this',storeKey)

return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawer {...props} />} screenOptions={headerStyles} initialRouteName={HomeScreen} >
        <Drawer.Screen name='Search' component={SearchScreen} options={QuitIcon}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Stock' component={StockScreen} options={QuitIcon} initialParams={{storeKey: storeKey}}/>
    </Drawer.Navigator>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Even if the UseEffect is async or none the following code will be the same,

when calling the `console.log('this', storeKey)` the data is not yet in the state, to wait the useEffect run before continue the code, you have to add an empty array as a second argument in the useEffect function like this :

```js
useEffect(() => {
  
}, []) // <-- empty array here
```

by this way your useEffect will be run only the first render of the app and the program will wait the useEffect to be run before continue.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579426/in-useeffect-whats-the-difference-between-providing-no-dependency-array-and-an for more details