# Why is my React Use-Effect Hook Not Working?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am re-posting a question I asked a week ago where I left out the steps I took to solve the issue. I am working on a simple MERN app off a tutorial and the use-effect function is not rendering the content onto the page. Here is the code:

### App.js File

```
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [listOfUsers, setListOfUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getUsersFakeDataGen").then((response) => {
      setListOfUsers(response.data)
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="usersDisplay">
        {listOfUsers.map((user) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <h1>Name: {user.name}</h1>
              <h1>Age: {user.age}</h1>
              <h1>Username: {user.username}</h1>
            </div>
          )
        })}
     </div>
    </div>
  )
};

export default App;
```

I tested the functionality by commenting out the "useEffect()" function and putting in an object in the "useState([])" element of "function App()". That object did correctly render on the page, but when I deleted that object and un-commented useEffect(), the page was blank again.

I confirmed that my APIs are working because my API client (Thunder Client) is showing that the GET and POST requests are reading and writing to the database (MongoDB). Also, the server is working properly (confirmed by a console log).

Any suggestions would be appreciated. If more information is needed, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: can you show us what response.data returns?

Comment: Adding to the above comment. Do you see any console errors in the browser ?

Comment: I have not coded in a long time and I'm still trying to re-learn some things. Where should I add the console log to see my output?

Comment: Please see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58579462/13658816) is of any help or value within this context.

Comment: The console logs (as is) would be helpful to see if there are errors. The code all looks correct, so I think that’s why we’re asking for more information. If you’d like to add another log for debugging, logging the response right before the setListOfUsers could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

if your problem is not resolved, yet I suggest the following:

```
  import axios from 'axios'
  ... 
  const [listOfUsers, setListOfUsers] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
     const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getUsersFakeDataGen").then((response) => {
     setListOfUsers(response.data)
     return response.data;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [])
```

Note `[]` in the useEffect, it means it will render only once when the page loads. Also I used `async` and `await` to wait for data to be retrieved before processing (maybe that's why you get empty elements). You can also `setState` outside of `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

function App() {
const [listOfUsers, setListOfUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getUsers").then((response) => {
      setListOfUsers(response.data)
    })
  }, [listOfUsers]); // THIS IS WHERE YOU ADD YOUR useEffect DEPENDENCIES

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="usersDisplay">
       {listOfUsers.map((user) => {
         return (
           <div>
             <h1>Name: {user.name}</h1>
             <h1>Age: {user.age}</h1>
             <h1>Username: {user.username}</h1>
            </div>
         )
        })}
    </div>
    </div>
 )

};

export default App;
```

OK look so the issue is if you only provided an empty array as your second argument. Your useEffect will only run one time, when you add stateful values to the array the useEffect will render every time that piece of state changes. If you omit the second argument the useeffect will run over and over again.

Also here-- Remember that you array starts empty, You need a check it's existence

```
{listOfUsers?.map.map((item))=>{}}
```

or

```
{listOfUsers.length && listOfUsers.map((item))=>{}}
```

.

```
    {listOfUsers.map((user) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Name: {user.name}</h1>
          <h1>Age: {user.age}</h1>
          <h1>Username: {user.username}</h1>
        </div>
      )
    })}
```