# React useEffect empty dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**The problem:**  when I remove the dependency array in `useEffect` the timer never stops. But when I add a dependency array in `useEffect` the timer gets stuck on `5`.

How can I solve this?

```
const App = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [target, setTarget] = useState([]);
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(5);

  const newQuestion = () => {
    const minimum = 1;
    const maximum = 10;
    const int1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
    const int2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
    setTarget([int1, int2]);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setScore(0);
    setTimer(5);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    newQuestion();
  }, [score]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer((prev) => {
        if (prev === 1) clearInterval(interval);
        return prev - 1;
      });
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  });

  const handleAnsewer = () => {
    const total = target[0] + target[1];

    if (total === Number(inputValue)) {
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else {
      if (score > 0) {
        setScore(score - 1);
      }
    }

    setInputValue("");

    newQuestion();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Random Math Quiz</h1>

      <h1> {target.join(" + ")} </h1>

      <h1> Timer: {timer} </h1>

      <input placeholder="Answer" value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)} />

      <div>
        <button disabled={timer === 0} onClick={handleAnsewer}>
          {" "}
          Submit{" "}
        </button>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button onClick={handleReset}> play again </button>
      </div>

      {score === 10 && <h1> (Score: 10 / {score}) Congrate you are master in Math!</h1>}
      {score <= 9 && timer < 1 && <h1> ( Score: 10 / {score}) Oh boy this is the math class!</h1>}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Please improve the clarity of the question

Comment: Yes I forgot to save the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-ride-gio2eb here is the quiz app the problem is here when I remove the dependency array in useEfffect  the timer is got - an infinite number and the play again button reset the timer to 5 but when I add dependency array  in useEffect the timer is stuck on 5.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579426/in-useeffect-whats-the-difference-between-providing-no-dependency-array-and-an

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `useEffect` containing the `setInterval` method with this one:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (timer > 0){ 
    setTimeout(() => {setTimer(timer - 1)}, 1000)
  }
}, [timer])
```

I think the approach with `setTimeout()` is better because you don't need to clear intervals or any of that nonsense.

### How it works

1. Is the condition met?
2. If yes, update `setTimer` to new time `timer - 1` after `1000ms`
3. `timer` changes and so it will trigger `useEffect` and the component will re-render
4. This will go on until the timer doesn't change. When it hits `0`