# componentWillUnmount lifecycle with react useeffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-lifecycle

Is there any difference with these 3 useEffects

```
useEffect(() => {
    return console.log('useEffect with undefined dep');
});

useEffect(() => {
    return console.log('useEffect with empty array dep');
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    return console.log('useEffect with filled dep');
}, [filledDep]);
```

Comment: yes there is, everything is explained in the official tutorial

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In useEffect, what's the difference between providing no dependency array and an empty one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579426/in-useeffect-whats-the-difference-between-providing-no-dependency-array-and-an)

Answer (score 1):

[As React docs says:](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

- when an empty array `[]` is supplied

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
> unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
> tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
> or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special
> case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always
> works.

- When there is no second argument, it works as both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`:

  ```
  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
      // Update the document title using the browser API
      document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });
  ```
- and if you supply arguments, then it will re-run the effect when arguments were changed and it will also still run after the initial render

  ```
  useEffect(() => {
      document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  }, [count]); // Only re-run the effect if count changes
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To clean up after a component unmounts, we have a simple way to perform the equivalent of the componentWillUnmount using the useEffect Hook.

The only thing that we need to do is to return a function inside the callback function of the useEffect Hook.

> if a component renders multiple times (as they typically do), the
> previous effect is cleaned up before executing the next effect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are...

1. It will run on every-time when component renders/re-renders
2. It will run only once when the component first renders
3. It will run when component first renders and every-time when its dependency `filledDep` changes.