# Expected infinite re-rendering but didn't happen

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [tmp, setTmp] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
    setTmp(count);
    console.log(tmp);
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        You clicked {count} times and temp is {tmp}
      </p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579426/in-useeffect-whats-the-difference-between-providing-no-dependency-array-and-an) I expected this to cause infinite re-render because a state `tmp` is getting changed inside the useEffect but it didn't, can someone please help what might be the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React setters ignore the set if the value didn't change. Repeatedly calling `setTmp(0)` will not trigger new renders. Change it to `setTmp(n => n+1)` and you will get the infinite loop you're looking for.

Comment: But count is getting changed, isn't it? Hence, setTmp is getting new value every time. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @cheems Every render with an update `count` costs 2 renders instead of 1. The second render doesn't trigger a new one: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-chihiro-fy7ytk?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Makes sense, but in the beginning why we have 2 times `Value not changed` instead of once? As per the link I mentioned it should runs first on mount and then on every re-render but no re-render occur until we click.

Comment: @cheems That is caused by Strict Mode (effects run twice). Remove it from index.ts and it will disappear.